# How to use flushleft with eqnarray*?

Tags: equations

I'm using WinEdit 9.0 along with MikeTex 2.9.

My document preamble reads as follows:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Article Class (This is a LaTeX2e document)  ********************
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% THEOREMS -------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
...
```

How do I use the `\begin{flushleft} \end{flushleft}` commands to cause the content of a `\begin{eqnarray*} \end{eqnarray*}` to start from the left margin in the `.pdf` output document, instead of (what it seems to me) its default setting of being centered?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `eqnarray*` (it's outdated), there are better ways (e.g `align*` etc from `amsmath`). `flushleft` should be replaced by `raggedleft` etc. And what erik said above ;-)

Comment: See [this answer to the question: eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/24974) for more about why it's good to [avoid eqnarray](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use the `amsmath` alignments than `eqnarray` but either way you get flush left equations by using

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, patching `flalign(*)` from `mathmath` into a `leftalign(*)` environment, with one optional argument: the equation indent (default `\parindent`):

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[showframe, noheadfoot, nomarginpar]{geometry} 
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \makeatletter
    \newenvironment{leftalign*}[1][\parindent]{\setlength\hangindent{#1}\start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue\m@ne}{\endalign}
    \newenvironment{leftalign}{\hangindent = \parindent \start@align\tw@\st@rredfalse\m@ne}{\endalign}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

    With \texttt{leftalign*}: 
    \begin{leftalign*}
       A & = B & \\
      C & = D + E + F + D + E + F + D + E + F + D + E + F = 4( D + E + F)& 
    \end{leftalign*}

    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.\\

    With \texttt{flalign*}: 
    \begin{flalign*}
        A & = B & & & & \\
       C & = D + E + F + D + E + F + D + E + F + D + E + F = 4( D + E + F)& &
    \end{flalign*}

    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]